# CoreOS in Vagrant - interfaces

Tags: systemd, bridge, docker, coreos

I'm trying to understand the networking model in CoreOS but I'm having trouble making the operating system bend to my will.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to use weave as an overlay network inside containers, to facilitate an IP+Port tuple, unique-per-service.

However, when testing CoreOS on my laptop with vagrant and virtualbox, I'm having trouble making CoreOS accept that the docker daemon should use a different cidr than 10.1.0.0/16. This despite having done:

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service /etc/systemd/system/
vim /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
```

and having this in `user-data`:

```
  3   units:
  2     - name: docker.service
  1       command: restart
  0       content: |
  1         [Unit]
  2         Description=Docker Application Container Engine
  3         Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
  4         After=docker.socket early-docker.target network.target
  5         Requires=docker.socket early-docker.target
  6
  7         [Service]
  8         Environment=TMPDIR=/var/tmp
  9         EnvironmentFile=-/run/flannel_docker_opts.env
 10         MountFlags=slave
 11         LimitNOFILE=1048576
 12         LimitNPROC=1048576
 13         ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/dockerd --daemon --host=fd:// --icc=false --fixed-cidr=172.17.42.0/16 $DOCKER_OPTS $    DOCKER_OPT_BIP $DOCKER_OPT_MTU $DOCKER_OPT_IPMASQ
 14
 15         [Install]
 16         WantedBy=multi-user.target
 17
```

I've restarted the machine, restarted docker and now I can't start because it tells me:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Fri 2015-03-06 08:53:40 UTC; 13s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 2331 ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/dockerd --daemon --host=fd:// --bridge=docker0 --icc=false --fixed-cidr=172.17.42.0/16 $DOCKER_OPTS $DOCKER_OPT_BIP $DOCKER_OPT_MTU $DOCKER_OPT_IPMASQ (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2331 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 dockerd[2331]: network does not contain specified subnet
Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 dockerd[2331]: time="2015-03-06T08:53:40Z" level="info" msg="-job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)"
Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 dockerd[2331]: time="2015-03-06T08:53:40Z" level="fatal" msg="network does not contain specified subnet"
Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 06 08:53:40 core-01 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Why is this?

Here's the docker0 interface:

```
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 56:84:7a:fe:97:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5484:7aff:fefe:9799/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a blip, or rather a `--bip=172.17.42.1/16` configuration setting, instead of fixed cidr.

You'll also have to manually tear down the bridge interface:

```
                 ip link set dev docker0 down
core-01 system # brctl delbr docker0
core-01 system # systemctl daemon-reload
core-01 system # systemctl start docker
core-01 system # journalctl -fu docker.service
```